# Inserting items in a Qt::TreeWidget

Tags: ruby, qt, qtruby

Using QtRuby (via [qtbindings](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings/)) I am trying to add items to a `QTreeWidget`. It says that it has a `insertTopLevelItems()` method, but it fails to respond to it:

```
hier = $my.appHierarchy
hier.column_count = 2
hier.header_labels = ['element', 'kind']
p hier.class, hier.methods.grep(/insert/)
#=> Qt::TreeWidget
#=> ["insertAction", "insertActions", "insertTopLevelItem", "insertTopLevelItems"]

hier.insertTopLevelItems ['x','y']
#=> in `method_missing': undefined method `insertTopLevelItems' for #<Qt::TreeWidget:0x007fc6c9153528> (NoMethodError)
```

How do I add items to this widget?

---

<sub>Ruby 2.0.0p353; Qt 4.8.6; OS X 10.9.5</sub>

Comment: One workaround is to insert the items during their creation directly, like so: `Qt::TreeWidgetItem.new(hier){ set_text 0, "My Label" }`

Answer (score 1):

You receive `method missing` because your arguments have the wrong type. Different from Ruby, C++  needs to match argument and result types, and so does the qtruby wrapper.

When calling `insertTopLevelItems` you are missing the index argument, and you must build a `Qt::TreeWidgetItem` from each string. If the tree is empty, `addTopLevelItem(...` does the same as `insertTopLevelItem(0,...`

Here is some example code to try:

```
(1..10).each do |n|
  item = Qt::TreeWidgetItem.new
  item.setText(0, "item #{n}/1")
  item.setText(1, "item #{n}/2")
  hier.insertTopLevelItem(0, item)
  #  hier.addTopLevelItem(item)  # same effect as previous line
end
```

or

```
itemlist = (1..10).collect do |n|
  item = Qt::TreeWidgetItem.new
  item.setText(0, "item #{n}/1")
  item.setText(1, "item #{n}/2")
  item
end
hier.insertTopLevelItems(0, itemlist)
#  hier.addTopLevelItems(itemlist)  # same effect as previous line
```