# Display an icon before text in a QTreeView

Tags: ruby, qt, treeview, qtreeview, qtruby

I'm using QtRuby with Qt 4.8.6 and trying to create a tree view where each item has a custom icon between the tree controls and the name. The end result should be like this:
                      [image: tree view with icons before each item]

I am getting space allocated for where the icon should go, but I'm not seeing any icons. What do I have to do to get them to show up?
                      [image: tree view with 2 columns, but no icons]

Here's my code (simplified slightly to remove the no-data edge cases):

```ruby
class MyModel < Qt::AbstractItemModel
  # ...
  def data(index, role)
    case role
      when Qt::DisplayRole
        case index.column
          when 0; Qt::Variant.new(index.internalPointer.displayName)
          when 1; Qt::Variant.new(index.internalPointer.displayType)
        end
      when Qt::DecorationRole
        if index.column==0 then
          # Just testing to show a static icon for all items
          Qt::Pixmap.new(':/resources/images/Objects-Scene-Normal.png')
        end
    end
  end
end

@mytreeview.model = MyModel.new
```

If you want to inspect the Qt Designer `.ui` file (in case the tree view needs to have a property set that I have not) it can be [seen here](https://github.com/Phrogz/RUIC/blob/7bd95fcc7936e19a9b755e2da70769a02a75e123/gui/window.ui).

Comment: I get the same results if I replace the path to the Pixmap with a path directly to an image. If I remove the `Qt::DecorationRole` altogether the empty space where the icons are supposed to go is removed; it's ALMOST doing the right thing.

Comment: If you use full path to the image file, try to escape backslashes if you are on Windows.

Comment: @vahancho Thank you for the advice, but please not from the code above that I am using forward slashes. Per comments below, the Pixmap is being found and is valid. I also experience similar results on OS X. (There as I resize the TreeView the empty gaps for the icons appear and disappear randomly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the `QPixmap` needs to be wrapped in a `QVariant` to work properly. This is done in QtRuby by using `Qt::Variant.fromValue()`:

```
when Qt::DecorationRole
  if index.column==0 then
    Qt::Variant.fromValue( Qt::Pixmap.new(':/path/to/resource') )
```

<sup>*Credit to **andre** and **peppe** on #qt irc.freenode.net for helping with this.*</sup>

Comment: Note that it is better to cache the pixmap or variant rather than creating a new instance each time the `data` method is called.

Answer (score 2):

I think the image cannot be found with the path specified. Verify it with [QFileInfo::exists()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#exists-2).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. They can be found:  `Qt::FileInfo.new(':/resources/images/Objects-Scene-Normal.png').exists #=> true`; the same is true if I change `:` to `.` or remove `:/`. If I edit the path to something nonsensical, the value becomes `false` as expected.

Comment: Then check if `QPixmap` actually loads the image file. Check `QPixmap::isNull()` or `QPixmap::size()`. Is Qt built with PNG support?

Comment: `pic.size #=> #<Qt::Size:0x007fcd1a8f24f8 width=16, height=16>`; `pic.isNull #=> false`. I have used PNG images in my menus, and I am able to add this same image resource (using Qt Designer) to a button and have it show up.

Answer (score 0):

use QTreeWidget insted of QTreeView.
then create a new form class (YourTreeWidgetItem) for your new items, every thing you like, then do this:

```
YourTreeWidgetItem* wItem = new YourTreeWidgetItem;
treeWidget->setItemWidget(wItem);
```

but it is c++ Qt code

Comment: I'd prefer not do to this as (a) [I have trouble properly inserting items in a TreeWidget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198356/inserting-items-in-a-qttreewidget) and (b) I chose a TreeView so that I wouldn't have to write all the logic for adding/removing items (recreating the whole model myself).