# Qt TreeView add text above decoration/image for item?

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, qtreewidget

I've managed to add an image to left of items in a QTreeView by returning the image during an overloaded QStandardItemModel::data() with role == Qt::DecorationRole. (This post was helpful for that: [Display an icon before text in a QTreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267294/display-an-icon-before-text-in-a-qtreeview))

So by default, QTreeView shows the text for the item to the right of the image. How can I make it show the text for the item above the image - next to the expander arrow, instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Derive a class from `QItemDelegate`, override `paint` method to taste. Feed the delegate to the view via `QTreeView::setItemDelegate`